# How can I strip html and word formatted text from a text box

Tags: asp.net, telerik, sitecore

I have a multiline textbox, need to restrict users from adding html input, any other scripts, copy pasting from word or any other word processer.
But I need to allow bullets for the input.

I thought it would be a simple thing to do since it looks like a common problem.
But I could not find a good solution in the web, please help. 
I am using telerik tool kit as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to strip out HTML then [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is your friend. It will deal with all manner of malformed html. As a bonus it is included in Sitecore already.

If you want to use something with a friendlier syntax then consider [CSQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) or [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) both of which provide you with a jQuery type syntax from within C#.

If you need to build a whitelist then take a look at [this post on how to add whitelist](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/215674):

```
public void RemoveNotInWhiteList(HtmlNode pNode, IEnumerable<string> pWhiteList)
{
    if (!pWhiteList.Contains(pNode.Name))
    {
        pNode.Remove();
        return;
    }

    pNode.Attributes
         .Where(att => !pWhiteList.Contains(att.Name))
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(att => att.Remove());            

    pNode.ChildNodes
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(att => RemoveNotInWhiteList(att, pWhiteList));
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the section regarding `pNode.ChildNodes` needs to be recursive to cover the entire document.  The article you linked does this.  I think you could also use xpath to get all the nodes recursively but I am still experimenting with this.

Comment: It is recursive, it's using LINQ ForEach to call the method as opposed to calling a foreach loop directly, that's all.

Comment: Wow, I guess I just wasn't reading carefully.  I think I was subconsciously reading `att.Remove()` like in the previous statement.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Validation rule, I reckon (in `/sitecore/System/Settings/Validation Rules`). Put the allowed HTML in a whitelist somewhere (possibly a Sitecore item), when validating run through that whitelist. If any other HTML tags appear in it, make it invalid.

This doesn't stop them from putting it in, but it will stop the item from being published.

You could even create a custom `item:saved` event handler which strips out all HTML tags apart from the whitelisted stuff. Again, it doesn't stop them from putting the HTML tags in, but as soon as the item is saved it will be removed. 
 Going even a step further than this, I think it also would be possible to use the Rules Engine for this - [this article by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Use-the-Sitecore-Rules-Engine-to-Control-Item-Names.aspx) shows how to use the Rules engine to modify item names, but you could modify it to read out specific text boxes.

Neither option here will stop users from inputting HTML, but the HTML tags will automatically be removed when the item is saved.